# How to center Github footers

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

As far as I can see, centering a Github footer is very hard.  So far,  I have tested:

```
<div style="center code">Footer</div>
<span style="center code">Footer</span>

|Message to be centered|
|:--------------------:|
```

All three have not worked.  Is there a way that works in footers?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<p align="center">
  <div class="footer">
            &copy; Example Stack Footer
        </div>
</p>
```

Wee need to use some inline css to make it works.

Take a look a [this](https://github.com/gnab/remark/wiki/Formatting) docs

Comment: try with <sup>Footer</sup>.

Comment: GitHub Flavored Markdown doesn't support footnotes, we need to fake it with some super script or unicode, let me see

Comment: I'm afraid neither of those worked @Ethaan, I don't think you can center them.

Comment: Popey that works for me, i center a image so it works do you wanna try it 1 more time?